# Crear objetos con refencias Node Js y MoongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola tengo las siguientes modelos de datos en mongo db

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Account",accountSchema);
```

Un segundo modelo

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var bundleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    bundle: String,
    ban: String,
    country: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Bundle",bundleSchema);
```

y una tercer modelo que relaciona ambos modelos

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var serviceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({    
    service: String,

    account:{         
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: "Account"
        },     
    bundle: {        
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Bundle"            
        }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Service",serviceSchema);
```

El problemo que tengo es a la hora de crear el objeto con las referencias
me indica que el siguiente error

> CastError : Cast to ObjectID failed for value " { account :
>   5bf32c6e43ff0338c69f20f}" at path "account"

este es el metodo que intento implementar para crear el objeto

```
router.post("/",function(req,res){     
    var serv = req.body.service;
    var accountName = {name:req.body.accName};
    var bundleName = {bundle:req.body.bdlNumber};

    Account.findOne(accountName,function(err,fAccount){
        if(err){console.log(err)}
        else{

            console.log(fAccount._id);
            var acc = {account:fAccount._id};

           Bundle.findOne(bundleName,function(err,fBundle){
            if(err){console.log(err);}
            else{
                console.log(fBundle._id);
                var bld = {id:fBundle._id };

                var newService = {service:serv,account:acc,bundle:bld}

                Service.create(newService,function(err,newlyCreated){
                    if(err){console.log(err);}
                    else{
                    console.log(fBundle.telco);
                    res.redirect("/services/")
                }})

            }
           })     
        }
    })
})
```

¿Como creo el objeto para despues poder popular los datos de los otros objetos?

Gracias

Comment: Hola Marco. El Id que estas pasando tiene 23 caracteres y no 24. Tienes que revisar que esta pasando que no llegan los 24 caracteres que necesita mongo.

Comment: Hola eso fue que lo copie manualmente por que no podia hacer copy  desde el powershell, el _id si esta pasando todos los caracteres, pero al parecer el casteo no es correcto o no espera ese tipo de parametro

Comment: Intenta cambiar `var newService = {service:serv,account:acc,bundle:bld}` por `var newService = {service:serv, account: fAccount._id,bundle:bld}`

En vez de pasar el objeto completo, solo pasa el id que recibiste de la busqueda.

Comment: Hola si eso era el error, muchas Gracias!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en la variable "newService" donde le pasas un objecto que tiene un key account y value acc, el valor de acc no es de typo "ObjectID" sino que es de tipo objecto y en el modelo le especificaste que account tiene que ser de tipo ObjectID, para corregirlo modifica lo siguiente:

```
var newService = {service:serv,account:acc.account,bundle:bld}
```

Comment: Amigo y disculpa la ignorancia soy nuevo en esto, como le paso un ObjectID?? .... no es lo mismo que el id que extraigo de los objetos encontrados???

Comment: Si es lo mismo, pero cuando declaras la variable "acc" le estas pasando un objecto el _id de mongodb(ObjectID) esta en "fAccount._id" solo tienes que hacer lo siguiente para obtenerlo y guardalo en "acc": "var acc = fAccount._id".

Comment: Si eso era, muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: Muy bien estamos aquí para ayudar.